# Zend Frameword 2: How to set a html link (img) in a legend of the fieldset?

Tags: zend-framework, zend-framework2

I used zf2 to design a website.
And the form is something like this:

```
$this->add(array
   'options'=>array(
            'label'=> 'title1'))
```

And finally it shows like this:

```
<form>
<fieldset>
    <legend>title1</legend>
    <label>****</label>
</fielset>
 </form>
```

Now, I wanna add a link or an image after the title1, for example:

```
<form>
<fieldset>
    <legend>title1<a href=''>link</a></legend>
    <label>****</label>
</fielset>
</form>
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

You can't. Well, at least not without overwriting the specific `ViewHelper` (probably `formCollection()`). In ZF2 all Labels are run through the [`Zend\View\Helper\EscapeHtml`](https://github.com/zendframework/zf2/blob/master/library/Zend/View/Helper/EscapeHtml.php) ViewHelper. Therefore using any sort of HTML inside Labels is not supported in any way.

While going by specification it may be allowed to use inline-elements inside the `<legend>` Element, semantically it looks a little different. The `<legend>` shall do nothing but to describe the contents of the `<fieldset>`.

Anyways, opinions aside, as i've mentioned, you'll have to overwrite the ViewHelper and then skip the use of the `EscapeHtml` ViewHelper, as it's done [in this line of the `formCollection()`](https://github.com/zendframework/zf2/blob/master/library/Zend/Form/View/Helper/FormCollection.php#L118) Code